# How to solve Tweepy’s BadStatusLine error

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, httplib

I developed a Twitter application with Python Tweepy API. It was working well for 3 months. Yesterday it stopped working. I tried some debugs to find the problem. I noticed that if i reduced the number of words that i follow, it starts to work. Normally i just follow 80 words. Whey do i get this error?

Here is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "murat.py", line 82, in <module>
    stream.filter(track=queries)
  File "/root/tas_test/tweepydll/tweepy/streaming.py", line 239, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/root/tas_test/tweepydll/tweepy/streaming.py", line 178, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/root/tas_test/tweepydll/tweepy/streaming.py", line 117, in _run
    resp = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1030, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
```

Code:

```
l = StdOutListener()
auto = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret) 
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(track=track_words, follow=follow_people)
```

Thanks in advance, regards.

Comment: Without providing any details of your code, it's almost impossible to answer your question. [BadStatusLine](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) might be thrown due to a broken/non-HTTP-Response, so you should inspect the response you get back. Is it a valid HTTP-Response?

Comment: code is this  l = StdOutListener()
        auto = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        stream = Stream(auth, l)
        stream.filter(track=track_words, follow=follow_people)